# Does MVC3 require a Model to be passed between views to maintain state?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model, razor

I have 8 pages labeled `Step0-Step7` that are used to save data incrementally to a model called `dr405`.  After `Step7`, I need to display an Upload.cshtml that creates a folder based on `DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePRopertyID` from my custom Profile provider.  So, as of right now I'm not posting anything from from `Step7` to the Upload.cshtml.  After Upload.cshtml I display an UploadSummary.cshtml that simply list the files located in the directory based on  `DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePRopertyID`.  Now,  I have to take the user to a `review` page that displays the DB persisted data for the dr405 model.  Does this mean I have to pass my model through Upload and UploadSummary as well even though those pages don't interact with the model?

My plan is to pass the ID as a hidden parameter from

step7 -> Upload -> UploadSummary -> Review(id) <--post accepts ID as parameter.  I'm not sure if this is the best way.

### Important point

I want to understand if I can do the same with the model

Step7(model) --> Upload(model) -->UploadSummary(model) -->Review(id Or Model)

```
public ActionResult Review(string id)
{
    var service = new DR405Service();

    var dr405 = db.dr405s.FirstOrDefault(d => d.TangiblePropertyId == id);


    return View(dr405);
}

    public ActionResult UploadSummary()
    {
        var saveLocation = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("\\"), "returns\\" + DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId);
        ViewData["files"] = Directory.GetFiles(saveLocation).ToList() ;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile)
    {
        var saveLocation = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("\\"), "returns\\" + DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(saveLocation);
        uploadfile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(saveLocation, Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName)));
        ViewData["UploadStatus"] = String.Format("File name: {0}, {1}Kb Uploaded Successfully.", uploadfile.FileName, (int)uploadfile.ContentLength / 1024);
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options to persist the data across requests.

You can use the MVC [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337884.aspx) feature. You can use the [Peek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.peek.aspx)/[Keep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728654.aspx) feature of TempData to keep it around until you need to dispose of it (as by default once the data is accessed it is deleted).

Session would also work, but isn't recommended due to it being harder to test in a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine.  Taking in the ID of a database entry is standard practice.  It requires less bandwidth, allows MVC to resolve the correct route/controller/action faster, and doesn't give bad guys as much surface are for sending malicious data to your server.

Comment: Is it correct to state that if I had 30 intermediary steps like Upload and UploadSummary I would need to pass in and back out the ID to each page so the next page could obtain the ID value?

Comment: Yes and TempData as Frazell suggested is an easy way of doing that